# why are the linear predictor coefficients obtained from OLS slightly different to those obtained from covariance?

Tags: r, least-squares, linear-model, covariance

consider the following R code

```
rm(list = ls())
set.seed(1234)
n = 1000
f = (n-1)/n
data = local({
  x1 = rnorm(n)
  x2 = x1 + rnorm(n)
  x3 = x2 - rnorm(n)
  x4 = x3 + rnorm(n)
  x5 = rnorm(n)
  x6 = x5 + x1 + rnorm(n)
  cbind(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6)
})

Y = data[,1:2]
X = data[,3:6]
m1 = lm(Y ~ X - 1)
a1 = m1$coefficients
a2 = solve(t(X)%*%X, t(X)%*%Y)
a3 = solve(cov(X), cov(X,Y))
```

`a1` is just the coefficients obtained from the built in ols function in R. `a2` is the "manual" way of calculating ols coefficients and `a1` is equal to `a2`.

`a3` is yet another way of calculating this, which I got from [here](https://www.randomservices.org/random/expect/Covariance.html#blp). `a3` is ever so slightly different to the other 2. Why? I thought it might be related to the `n-1` divisor used to calculate covariance, but when I adjusted for that, it didn't make a difference.

Comment: `a2` is the solution without an intercept.  `a3` uses an intercept.

Comment: ok, I get it. If I had calculated the covariance using expected values of zero (if that makes sense) then it would match, right?

Comment: That sounds just like the calculation you are doing to find `a2` except that you would be dividing both arguments of `solve` by the same constant, which cancels out.